# Why does this multi-phase buck controller have one phase to be driven by external driver?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, mosfet-driver

https://www.renesas.com/in/en/document/dst/isl62883-isl62883b-datasheet

"The ISL62883 uses two integrated gate drivers and an external gate driver to provide a complete solution"

[image]

Why would they have this kinda weird solution? Is it to reduce the size of IC yet make it compatible for high power application (3 phase operation)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a compromise.
Easier on chip real estate, thermal&current requirements.
You would hardly select a multi-phase controller for a single-phase converter, but if you target 2-phase, one driver would be wasted.
The external driver for 3-phase operation is a commodity item…

Possibly most attractive if there is at least one 2-phase and one 3-phase converter in a single design.

Comment: Indeed, data sheet indicates: "Programmable 1-, 2- or 3-Phase Operation". So the third phase is an option, and only in this case you'd require the additional external driver.